# Access class and create objects

Tags: java, class

i'm trying to access a class named "Person" which has only one argument, "name" here's my class:

```
class person{
  String name;
   public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
   public String getName(){ return name; }
  }
```

And then on my main class i've got the following:

```
public class exercise{
   public static void main(String []args){
   Person person [] = new Person [20];
   person[0].setName("zgur");
   System.out.printf(""+person[0].getName());
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

What am i missing and/or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following:

```
Person[] people = new Person[20];
people[0] = new Person("Harry");
people[1] = new Person("Alan");
...etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an array but not filling it with objects. Think of an array of reference type like an egg crate. Until you fill it with eggs, you can't use any of the eggs in the crate.

So change to:

```
// note that class names should begin with an uppercase letter
public class Exercise{
   public static void main(String []args){
     Person[] people = new Person [20];
     for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
       people[i] = new Person();       }
     people[0].setName("zgur");
     System.out.printf("" + people[0].getName());
   }
}
```

---

If this were my code, I'd consider using an `ArrayList<Person>` and only add a Person if and when needed. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
  personList.add(new Person("Stan"));  // assuming that a String constructor exists
  personList.add(new Person("Bill"));
}
```

Comment: And how can i do that? I'm trying to apply an exercise that i learnt in class that's why i'm doing this :)

Comment: @user3188598: Fill the array with a for loop. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: So before trying to add data to the object, when i declare the amount of objects that i'll allow i must initialise them? For example, instead of declaring 20, i had declared 5000 i need to make the FOR CYCLE, to initialise them as null and afterwards i could start filling it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3188598: if this were my code, I'd likely use an `ArrayList<Person>`, which is likely a flexible variable-sized array (but different), and only create and add Person objects as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that here you don't create a Person instance:

> Person person [] = new Person [20];

Here you create an array of 20 references, but every reference is initialized with **null**.
So accessing zeroe's element as

> person[0].setName("zgur");

you are getting the NPE.

If you really need to use an array to work with your Person instances, ensure that you have initialized the item you're addressing:

> person[0] = new Person();
>
> person[0].setName("whateverYouNeed");

Just a little note: it's preferable to use the followed form of array creation:

> Person[] person = new Person[20];

with [] after the reference type.